# How to recover a deleted user account

Tags: 12.04, user-management, undelete

I have deleted a user account using the command `userdel -r george`.
It deleted that user with their files.
I need to restore that user and their files, is it possible? How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily, no. The files have been deleted, you will need to use a tool that can recover deleted files, there is no undo for this. For help on recovering deleted files, see this Q&A:

[How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/q/3883/85695)

Recreating the user is the easy part:

```
adduser george
```

For future reference, user management should be done with [`adduser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man8/adduser.8.html) and [`deluser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/deluser.8.html) instead of `useradd` and `userdel`.